# Wrong referenced assembly

Tags: c#, adomd.net

Getting the following error when attempting to build my solution.  I'm fairly certain I've done it on this machine before but it's been many months.  I'm not sure what might have changed in the meantime.

```
Assembly uses 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient' with identity 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient, Version=8.0.700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
```

I have attempted to remove every mention of 8.0.700.0 from my computer via the SSDT (un)installer and manual deletion of files and registry entries and gacutil.  The project is configured to use 10.0, but I cannot figure out how it even knows that a 8.0.700.0 version exists in the first place.

As far as I know, nothing remains in the registry, or the GAC, or the assemblies folders for version 8.0.700.0.
Any idea what is going on here?

Currently in the GAC

```
$ gacutil /l | grep Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient,
  Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL
  Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL
  Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL
  Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL
```

Comment: try removing the reference then add it back again - something may have got updated in those last few months.

Comment: did you install a newer version of .net framework..? what version of .net framework is your current project using when you right click on the project and select the Application from the right hand  side.

Comment: I removed the reference and I cannot add it back from the list, which seems to suggest something is messed up.  No versions of Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient are listed under Assemblies.


This is what I currently have in the GAC: edit: too long added to original post.

Comment: The error is telling you that *some* assembly in your code is referencing version 8.0.700.0. This need not be your assembly, it can be any assembly in your solution, referencing any other assembly, and so on recursively. The normal solution to this (if you're not going to rebuild everything from scratch) is to set up an assembly binding redirect to send everything prior to 10.0.0.0 to 10.0.0.0.

Comment: Well I'd bet messing about in the registry to remove references to 8.0.700.0 is what's screwed you up, even though you thought you wanted the 10.0 often it itself may have refereed back to the older ones/sub libs.  Guess you're just going to have to reinstall whatever put it there in the first place.

Comment: I noticed that the 2 places its having an issue have in the reference properties a Path to where the 8.0 version was installed.

I guess I'll try the reinstall and see what that does.

Comment: I reinstalled the 8.0.700.0 version, so now the path of the referenced assembly is valid again, but it didn't change the error.